# Why isn't array filling?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to fill two arrays with an fstream. One is string and one is int. The string array (name) populates fine, but the char array only populates the first value.

```
void fillInventory(ifstream &fin, int costArray[],string itemArray[])
{
    string name = "junk";
    string cost;
    int i = 0;
    int max = 0;
    stringstream convert;

    while(name != "none")
    {
        getline(fin, name);
        getline(fin, cost);
        if(name != "none")
        {
            itemArray[i] = name;
            convert<<cost;
            convert >> costArray[i];
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Am I using stringstream wrong or is my logic off, or something else altogether?

Comment: The cost is a whole number, correct?

Comment: Yes, I thought that'd be the simplest way for me.

Comment: Is your whole int array filled with the first value, or is only the first element of the array filled?

Comment: Try moving decl of convert to the same block as its use?

Comment: @Chris, it was only the first value getting filled, the rest stayed at 0(the initialized value)

Comment: @DanielBall, As per my answer, moving the declaration creates a new one with a fresh state instead of using one that previously failed. If you want something to play around with, try toggling the `clear()` comment in this: http://liveworkspace.org/code/18bfb06799a58b653408ee6c8161c861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
convert >> costArray[i];
```

You've reached the EOF on the stringstream, which sets the `eofbit` flag, causing future operations to fail. Reset the flags in order to continue:

```
convert >> costArray[i];
convert.clear();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks guys. Wish I could give you both an accept. What flag is it setting, can you explain a bit or point me at a good reference?(I just started learning in September ...)

Comment: @DanielBall, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream. When `operator>>` hits EOF, it sets `eofbit`, meaning it reached the end of file. This leaves future operations to leave things unmodified. You'd also see this behaviour if you `cin` an int, but enter a character. Using `clear()` resets the flags. The nice thing about `fail()` returning `true` on EOF is that it allows for a nice loop: `while (cin >> num)`, or `while (fin >> num)`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll try to remember this.